# Is it possible to search an apt repository via a web browser?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, repository, ubuntu-10.04, internet

I've installed the beta version of Ubuntu 10.04 server edition (x64), but the system doesn't have an internet connection. Is there a way I can find out what packages are in the apt repository with nothing more than a web browser?

The reason I'm asking, is because I will have an internet connection available when the production system goes live, but it simply isn't possible to internet connect my development system.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) allows you to browse and search all the packages that are available in each Ubuntu release.

You can also look at the packages file of an apt repository. For example
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz and http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz are the lists of packages in the Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid and 20.04 Focal main distributions for amd64 processors. Browse the directory trees to see the other available distributions. You'll find the referenced packages for all currently supported releases under http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/ and previous releases under http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/.

Comment: How would this work for other repositories than the Ubuntu one?

Comment: the first is a deadlink

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com)